# How to sum a column UP TO "this" cell?

Tags: spreadsheet

I'm using Google Sheets but hoping for others' sake a general answer might work here. See the screenshot below. When I insert a row below the column containing "$37.50" and I enter a number in the new row for that column, this `sum` function doesn't pick it up because it becomes `F23` and the total then becomes `F24`. Every time I do this, I need to edit this cell's `sum` function. Is it possible to do something like `sum(CELL1:THIS_CELL - 1)`?

Any help would be great, thanks!

I[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to obtain the address of a cell immediately above current cell use

```
ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())
```

To obtain the reference to it, use

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))
```

So in your particular case you may replace your formula with

```
=SUM(F18:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))
```

---

PS. When I select F23, insert a cell with cells moving down, enter a value into newly inserted empty cell and press Enter (or click another cell) - Excel automatically edits the formula in F24 cell to =SUM(F18:F23)...

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with Excel?

Comment: @user49256 ??? why?